# Running out of Memory for Folium Map

Tags: python, pandas, memory, ram, folium

I have been using the enclosed code to build an HTML file that contains a folium map with many markers from a dataframe. I had been using it perfectly until today. Now it hangs for a long time and gives me a memory error when saving the html file. When I comment out the HTML file line, the code runs after a while.

Why would I be getting this error now?

Can my code be made more efficient?

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
import folium.plugins as plugins
import folium.map as fm


df = pd.read_excel('Stores_lat_long.xlsx')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Store Latitude'])
df = df.dropna(subset=['Store Longitude'])


sf = pd.read_excel('Stores_lat_long.xlsx', 1, index_col=0)

#oh / (sales/6)

sf['WOS'] = sf['Repl Inv Units'] / (sf['Sales Units'] / 6)

df = pd.merge(df, sf)

print(df)


#defining inital Map Object
m = folium.Map(
    location=[36.166340, -86.779068], 
    zoom_start=4)

folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap').add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Terrain').add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Toner').add_to(m)



#Define Features

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Hardwood Only Stores Code 01', show=False)
m.add_child(fg)

gg = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Softwood Only Stores Code 01', show=False)
m.add_child(gg)

fgcl = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Hardwood Clustered', show=False)
fgcl_markers = plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(fgcl)
m.add_child(fgcl)


ggcl = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Softwood Clustered', show=False)
ggcl_markers = plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(ggcl)
m.add_child(ggcl)

# tie to top right layer control

folium.LayerControl('topright', collapsed=False).add_to(m)

#Hardwood Pellets un-clusterd

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df['Std Code'].iloc[i] != 1: continue
    if df['Article No'].iloc[i] != 3195163: continue

    sku = df['Article No'].iloc[i]
    store = df['Store No'].iloc[i]
    code = df['Std Code'].iloc[i]
    units = df['Repl Inv Units'].iloc[i]
    oo = df['On Order Units'].iloc[i]
    region = df['Region Full'].iloc[i]
    dm = df['Dist DM Name'].iloc[i]
    wos = df['WOS'].iloc[i]


    test = folium.Html('''

        <body>
            Store Number: <strong> {store} </strong> <br>
            Pellet SKU: <strong> {sku} </strong> <br>
            Store Coded: <strong> {code} </strong> <br>
            On-Hand Units: <strong> {units} </strong> <br>
            On-Order Units: <strong> {oo} </strong> <br>
            Region: <strong> {region} </strong> <br>
            DM: <strong> {dm} </strong> <br>
            WOS: <strong> {wos} </strong> <br>

        </body>'''.format(sku=sku, store=store, code=code, units=units, region=region, dm=dm, oo=oo,wos=wos), script=True)

    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.Marker(
                [df['Store Latitude'].iloc[i], df['Store Longitude'].iloc[i]], 
                popup=popup,
                tooltip= 'Store:' + str(df['Store No'].iloc[i]), 
                icon=folium.Icon(color='darkred',icon="home", prefix='fa')).add_to(fg)
    continue


#Softwood Pellets Unclustered
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df['Article No'].iloc[i] != 1115622: continue
    if df['Std Code'].iloc[i] != 1: continue

    sku = df['Article No'].iloc[i]
    store = df['Store No'].iloc[i]
    code = df['Std Code'].iloc[i]
    units = df['Repl Inv Units'].iloc[i]
    oo = df['On Order Units'].iloc[i]
    region = df['Region Full'].iloc[i]
    dm = df['Dist DM Name'].iloc[i]
    wos = df['WOS'].iloc[i]

    test = folium.Html('''

        <body>
            Store Number: <strong> {store} </strong> <br>
            Pellet SKU: <strong> {sku} </strong> <br>
            Store Coded: <strong> {code} </strong> <br>
            On-Hand Units: <strong> {units} </strong> <br>
            On-Order Units: <strong> {oo} </strong> <br>
            Region: <strong> {region} </strong> <br>
            DM: <strong> {dm} </strong> <br>
            WOS: <strong> {wos} </strong> <br>

        </body>'''.format(sku=sku, store=store, code=code, units=units, region=region, dm=dm, oo=oo, wos=wos), script=True)

    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.Marker(
                [df['Store Latitude'].iloc[i], df['Store Longitude'].iloc[i]], 
                popup=popup,
                tooltip= 'Store:' + str(df['Store No'].iloc[i]), 
                icon=folium.Icon(color='blue',icon="building", prefix='fa')).add_to(gg)
    continue


#Hardwood Clustered
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df['Std Code'].iloc[i] != 1: continue
    if df['Article No'].iloc[i] != 3195163: continue


    sku = df['Article No'].iloc[i]
    store = df['Store No'].iloc[i]
    code = df['Std Code'].iloc[i]
    units = df['Repl Inv Units'].iloc[i]
    oo = df['On Order Units'].iloc[i]
    region = df['Region Full'].iloc[i]
    dm = df['Dist DM Name'].iloc[i]
    wos = df['WOS'].iloc[i]


    test = folium.Html('''

        <body>
            Store Number: <strong> {store} </strong> <br>
            Pellet SKU: <strong> {sku} </strong> <br>
            Store Coded: <strong> {code} </strong> <br>
            On-Hand Units: <strong> {units} </strong> <br>
            On-Order Units: <strong> {oo} </strong> <br>
            Region: <strong> {region} </strong> <br>
            DM: <strong> {dm} </strong> <br>
            WOS: <strong> {wos} </strong> <br>

        </body>'''.format(sku=sku, store=store, code=code, units=units, region=region, dm=dm, oo=oo, wos=wos), script=True)

    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.Marker(
                [df['Store Latitude'].iloc[i], df['Store Longitude'].iloc[i]], 
                popup=popup,
                tooltip= 'Store:' + str(df['Store No'].iloc[i]), 
                icon=folium.Icon(color='darkred',icon="home", prefix='fa')).add_to(fgcl_markers)
    continue



#Softwood Clustered
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df['Article No'].iloc[i] != 1115622: continue
    if df['Std Code'].iloc[i] != 1: continue

    sku = df['Article No'].iloc[i]
    store = df['Store No'].iloc[i]
    code = df['Std Code'].iloc[i]
    units = df['Repl Inv Units'].iloc[i]
    oo = df['On Order Units'].iloc[i]
    region = df['Region Full'].iloc[i]
    dm = df['Dist DM Name'].iloc[i]
    wos = df['WOS'].iloc[i]

    
    test = folium.Html('''

        <body>
            Store Number: <strong> {store} </strong> <br>
            Pellet SKU: <strong> {sku} </strong> <br>
            Store Coded: <strong> {code} </strong> <br>
            On-Hand Units: <strong> {units} </strong> <br>
            On-Order Units: <strong> {oo} </strong> <br>
            Region: <strong> {region} </strong> <br>
            DM: <strong> {dm} </strong> <br>
            WOS: <strong> {wos} </strong> <br>

        </body>'''.format(sku=sku, store=store, code=code, units=units, region=region, dm=dm, oo=oo, wos=wos), script=True)

    

    popup = folium.Popup(test, max_width=2650)
    folium.Marker(
                [df['Store Latitude'].iloc[i], df['Store Longitude'].iloc[i]], 
                popup=popup,
                tooltip= 'Store:' + str(df['Store No'].iloc[i]), 
                icon=folium.Icon(color='blue',icon="building", prefix='fa')).add_to(ggcl_markers)
    continue



m.save(outfile='pellet_map2.html')
df.to_excel('ThisOne.xlsx')
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXm6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was merging two data frames incorrectly and the resulting df was 55,000+ lines. My map was trying to plot out all those points in a chrome browswer... which was way too much. Folium maps top out around 3000 points before freezing your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering this question - but a tip to reduce folium HTML file size:

Simplify your geoDataFrame with `gpd.simplify(tolerance=0.1)` -- the higher the tolerance, the more distorted your polygon file becomes.

My folium HTML size reduced from 70mb to less than an mb after doing this.

Comment: Please answer the question otherwise put this information as a comment